# NGINX - Unable to proxy to another domain

Tags: nginx

I have the following domain ...

```
https://example.com/verify/4545/joe@example.com
```

I need that to proxy the following URL:

```
https://api.example.com/verify/4545/joe@example.com
```

I've tried:

```
location /verify/ {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass https://api.example.com/verify/;
}
```

and

```
location /verify {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass https://api.example.com;
}
```

Both return a 502 error. How can I proxy this way?

Comment: Can you try `return 307 https://api.example.com$request_uri` instead of `proxy_pass` ?

Comment: Is there a corresponding entry in the `nginx` error log?

Comment: @IVOGELOV yup that works fine. I didn't really want to expose the api address to the end user but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper and find the root cause - you should look at all the logs you have (both for nginX and the proxy recipient - if it is not the same nginX) or even put `events { debug_connection 1.2.3.4; }` with your IP into `nginx.conf` (assuming you have built nginX with debug info). It may be as simple as missing `proxy_set_header Host $host;` but only logs can tell you the truth (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)